# Get path to a ruby project's root directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

My ruby project looks like this:

```
my_dir
   - app
       + controllers
       + views
       + models
           * foo.rb
   - doc
       + dummy.txt
```

Inside `foo.rb`, I have a constant, which is used as below

```
PATH_TO_DUMMY="../../doc/dummy.txt"
def bar(path=PATH_TO_DUMMY)
   # do something
end
```

Is "../../doc/dummy.txt" the correct way to define path to `<my_dir>/doc/dummy.txt`?
It doesn't look alright, because that's only the correct path from `app/models`

Is there a way to get the absoutely path to my project directory, so I can just do something like:

```
PATH_TO_DUMMY=File.jon(PROJECT_ROOT, "doc/dummy.txt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.join(Rails.root, "doc", "dummy.txt")
```

or

```
Rails.root.join("doc", "dummy.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Rails.root` to get the path of project's directory. In your case it will be

`PATH_TO_DUMMY=File.join(Rails.root, "doc/dummy.txt")`